# What is the nhi event source and its event id 1 in the Microsoft windows system event log?

Tags: windows, event-log

On a Dell Precision 7720 laptop running Microsoft Windows 10, Version 20H2, OS Build 19042.867, I see the following event showing up in the Windows System event log:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="nhi" /> 
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">1</EventID> 
    <Version>0</Version> 
    <Level>4</Level> 
    <Task>0</Task> 
    <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-03-24T09:48:49.4168316Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>143446</EventRecordID> 
    <Correlation /> 
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="22492" /> 
    <Channel>System</Channel> 
    <Computer>Precision-7720</Computer> 
    <Security /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data /> 
    <Binary>00000000010000000000000001000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</Binary> 
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I see that the process that is causing this event is the System process (ProcessID 4). I am wondering which provider / component is causing this event and what event id 1 for this source means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NHI is  Native Host Interface. I would suggest that it is related to the thunderbolt driver for your Dell. Make sure all your drivers are up to date and you are running the latest BIOS.

https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/precision-17-7720-laptop/drivers

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The system indeed has a Thunderbolt 3 controller, so Native Host Interface sounds plausible. Do you also happen to know what event id 1 means? When I view the general information of the event in event viewer, I get the message: `The description for Event ID 1 from source nhi cannot be found.`

Comment: Event ID is just a unique number for the "NHI" event source. The vendor that publishes and logs these events makes up these numbers.

The fact that the description can't be found means that the DLL, which contains the template for these events, is either missing or not registered correctly.

Just like bitcollision mentioned, I would make sure that all applicable drivers and SW from DELL is installed, that may fix the issue.

Comment: I found out that all event sources are actually registered in the Windows Registry under the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog`. On my computer, the `nhi` event source is listed there under the `System` key (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\System`) with an `EventMessageFile` value of `c:\windows\system32\iologmsg.dll;c:\windows\system32\drivers\tbt100x.sys`. The `tbt100x.sys` file has a File description of `Thunderbolt(TM) Bus Driver`, confirming that the nhi event source is associated with the Thunderbolt controller.

Comment: I also found a couple of other registry keys named `nhi`:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\nhi`
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\FirstBoot\Services\nhi`

And a key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_15D9&SUBSYS_07B11028&REV_02\F2A824120BB7D00000` containing a value named `service` with data `nhi`.

Apparently, next to an event source, `nhi` is also a driver service running under the System process. I assume it is this service that is causing the event.